# Problem with building dynamic BottomNavigation NS 6.5

Tags: javascript, nativescript

NS 6.5 has been released and there is a new feature: Dynamic Creation of Tabs and Bottom Navigation...

I followed their example but it seems not working, see my code below in a playground:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=SoGnxo&v=6

Please help to fix if I am doing anything wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. Here are all of them explained:

1.You have wrong imports. For example, there is a missing StackLayout import and also a wrong import for the BottomNavigation class.

```
const Color = require("tns-core-modules/color").Color;
const Label = require("tns-core-modules/ui/label").Label;
const StackLayout = require("tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout").StackLayout;
const BottomNavigation = require("tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation").BottomNavigation;
const TabStrip = require("tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation").TabStrip;
const TabStripItem = require("tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation").TabStripItem;
const TabContentItem = require("tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation").TabContentItem;
```

2.You are creating an "empty" **BottomNavigaiton** within the XML. That is not needed and could cause trouble (as there are no ***tabStrip*** and ***content*** items initialized). Remove the BottomNavigation tag from the XML and create it dynamically via the code-behind logic.

3,You are creating bottom navigation via code-behind, but there is no code that actually adds this newly created component anywhere on the page. You could use the **content** property of the current page.

```
  var bottomNavigaiton = new BottomNavigation();

  /* TabStrip creating and adding to BottomNavigation.tabStrip */
  let myTabStrip = new TabStrip();
  let tabStripItem1 = new TabStripItem();
  tabStripItem1.title = "Tab 1";

  // To use icon font, you need to have a fonts folder with FontAwesome added in the project
  // tabStripItem1.iconSource = `font://${String.fromCharCode(0xf053)}`;
  // tabStripItem1.iconClass = "fas"; // e.g., Font Awesome
  let tabStripItem2 = new TabStripItem();
  tabStripItem2.title = "Tab 2";
  // To use icon font, you need to have a fonts folder with FontAwesome added in the project
  // tabStripItem2.iconSource = `font://${String.fromCharCode(0xf070)}`;
  // tabStripItem2.iconClass = "fas"; // e.g., Font Awesome
  myTabStrip.items = [tabStripItem1, tabStripItem2];
  bottomNavigaiton.tabStrip = myTabStrip;

  /* TabContent items creating and adding to BottomNavigation.items */
  let tabContentItem1 = new TabContentItem();
  tabContentItem1.content = createContent(1);
  let tabContentItem2 = new TabContentItem();
  tabContentItem2.content = createContent(2);
  let contentItems = [tabContentItem1, tabContentItem2];
  bottomNavigaiton.items = contentItems;

  /* 
    Adding the created bottom navigation to the Page content
  */
  page.content = bottomNavigaiton;
```

4. You don't have a fonts folder that contains the icon fonts (FontAwesome).

See the whole revised example here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=SoGnxo&v=16

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickIliev, it seems it doesn't change tabContentItem when I click on tabStripItem

Comment: It is but because your createContent function is expecting a number and you are passing a string it is always setting the same text for the different content pages.